# Get the current time in a dataflow

Tags: atrius-solution-builder

I'm building a dataflow where I want to filter rows based on the current time. I need to filter these based on the hour and minute.

I thought I could use a Date Time block. When I use that, the output value shows "today".

[image: properties of a Date Time block showing the output value of "today"]

But when I bind the output of the Date Time block to the input on a Date Format block or my symbol, the value of the bound property is `null`.

[image: properties showing the bound value is null]

I'm looking for a way to get the current date and time, preferably with a way to control how often the value is updated (once per minute would be enough for example).

Answer (score 2):

Using a Script block works. The script to get the current timestamp with the precision of one minute as a string:

```
dateFormat(new DateTime(), "y-MM-dd HH:mm")
```

You can connect the output of the Script block to the input on a block that expects a "date", such as a Date Format block.

For the value to be updated, you must invoke the script block. To do this, a Stopwatch block can be used. In my case, I have it set to update every 10 seconds.

[image: a Stopwatch block at left with its onLoop action connected to the invoke action on a Script block]